# How to use SOCKS 5 proxy with TIdUDPClient properly

Tags: c++, proxy, udp, c++builder

I'm trying to use SOCKS v5 proxy with `TIdUDPClient`. I'm using C++ Builder 10.3 in Windows x64.

Here is my code so far:

```
TIdSocksInfo* socksInfo = new TIdSocksInfo();
socksInfo->Host = "ip address of the proxy server";
socksInfo->Port = proxyPort;
socksInfo->Version = svSocks5;
socksInfo->Authentication = saNoAuthentication;

IdUDPClient1->Host = "ip address of my udp server";
IdUDPClient1->Port = port;
IdUDPClient1->TransparentProxy = socksInfo;
IdUDPClient1->Connect();
```

I can connect to my server perfectly without the proxy.

But, it fails to connect with the proxy, so I sniffed the network with wireshark:

[image: Capture Result]

The UDP client sends "0.0.0.0" and 0 as the remote info, instead of sending the host and port I set in the code.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Please show the code for how you are sending datagrams to the target server after calling `Connect()`.  Those are the datagrams you are missing, and that has nothing to do with the `UdpAssociate` request that `Connect()` sends to the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdUDPClient::Connect()` will call `TIdSocksInfo::OpenUDP()` to send a UDP ASSOCIATION request to a SOCKS v5 proxy.  `TIdUDPClient` passes its `Host` and `Port` property values as parameters to `OpenUDP()`.

However, `TIdSocksInfo::OpenUDP()` ignores these Host and Port values that are passed to it.  It is hard-coded to send IP `0.0.0.0` (or `::0` for IPv6) and port `0` to the SOCKS proxy.  And this is OK, per the SOCKS v5 spec, [RFC 1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928):

> UDP ASSOCIATE
>
> The UDP ASSOCIATE request is used to establish an association within the UDP relay process to handle UDP datagrams.  **The DST.ADDR and DST.PORT fields contain the address and port that the client expects to use to send UDP datagrams on for the association.**  The server MAY use this information to limit access to the association.  **If the client is not in possesion of the information at the time of the UDP ASSOCIATE, the client MUST use a port number and address of all zeros.**
>
> A UDP association terminates when the TCP connection that the UDP ASSOCIATE request arrived on terminates.
>
> **In the reply to a UDP ASSOCIATE request, the BND.PORT and BND.ADDR fields indicate the port number/address where the client MUST send UDP request messages to be relayed.**

So, in a UDP ASSOCIATION request, the specified Host/Port is the **local Host/Port** that the client will send outgoing datagrams from, or zeros if it does not know that info yet.  This lets the proxy's UDP relay know where datagrams will come from when datagrams are being sent from the client to a target peer, and where to send datagrams to when datagrams are being sent from a target peer to the client.  If the requested Host/Port is all zeros, the relay should simply use the Host/Port that sent the request.

The Host/Port specified in a UDP ASSOCIATION request is *NOT* the target peer Host/Port that datagrams are to be forwarded to, like you are thinking.  That target info is specified in the individual datagrams that the client will pass to the proxy for forwarding *AFTER* the association is created.  Unlike TCP, UDP is connection-less, so a client can create a single association and then send datagrams to multiple targets, if it wants to.

There is no connection in UDP, so there is nothing for the proxy to send to the target server while processing a UDP ASSOCIATION request.  It is simply setting up the proxy's listening port that will then relay subsequent datagrams between the client and the target server.

When sending datagrams for forwarding afterwards, `TIdUDPClient::SendBuffer()` will call `TIdSocksInfo::SendToUDP()`, which is also passed the `TIdUDPClient`'s `Host` and `Port` property values. `SendUDP()` will then send a datagram with that target info to the proxy's relay port:

> **A UDP-based client MUST send its datagrams to the UDP relay server at the UDP port indicated by BND.PORT in the reply to the UDP ASSOCIATE request.**  If the selected authentication method provides encapsulation for the purposes of authenticity, integrity, and/or confidentiality, the datagram MUST be encapsulated using the appropriate encapsulation.  Each UDP datagram carries a UDP request header with it:
>
> ... [request header, containing DST.ADDR and DST.PORT in it] ...
>
> When a UDP relay server decides to relay a UDP datagram, it does so silently, without any notification to the requesting client. **Similarly, it will drop datagrams it cannot or will not relay.**  When a UDP relay server receives a reply datagram from a remote host, it MUST encapsulate that datagram using the above UDP request header, and any authentication-method-dependent encapsulation.
>
> **The UDP relay server MUST acquire from the SOCKS server the expected IP address of the client that will send datagrams to the BND.PORT given in the reply to UDP ASSOCIATE.  It MUST drop any datagrams arriving from any source IP address other than the one recorded for the particular association.**
>
> ...

So, whatever problem you are having with communicating with your target server, it is likely not related to `TIdUDPClient1::Connect()` at all, it is more likely related to `TIdUDPClient::SendBuffer()` and `TIdUDPClient::ReceiveBuffer()` instead.  Either:

- the proxy's UDP relay is ignoring the datagrams that `TIdUDPClient` is requesting be forwarded to the target server, or it is ignoring the server's replies.
- datagrams are getting lost in flight on their way to the target server, or on their way back to the proxy.

If you sniff `TIdUDPClient`'s traffic again and see your actual communication datagrams targeting your server properly, then you are going to have to sniff the traffic on the other side of the proxy to make sure those datagrams are actually being forwarded onward.  If they are, then the problem has to be on the network or the server itself.  If they are not, then the problem has to be on the proxy itself.